# VBA issue - loop through every worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a macro with a loop logic that I copied off of another stackoverflow/ms support page, but it doesn't seem to work.

I am not experienced with VBA so I am having trouble figuring out why the 'loop through all worksheets' part isn't working.

Can anyone please take a look at my code and tell me how it can be fixed?

```
Sub HideEmptyRows()
    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws_count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For i = 1 To ws_count
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each Current In Worksheets
            ' This code hides the adv and group merch rows
            For Each cell In Range("eq29", "eq51")
                If cell.Value = 0 Then
                    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Else
                    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If

            Next cell

            ' This code hides the consulting rows
            For Each cell In Range("eq61", "eq172")
                If cell.Value = 0 Then
                    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Else
                    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            Next cell
        Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I like the idea of throwing in a With Current after the for Each Current line and then a period before the Range in each of the For Each cell lines and End With after the last Next cell.

Unless there is a compelling reason (ie the tests are different or will be) why don't you combine the ranges/cell loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

You have not assigned any of the range objects to a parent sheet so it only works on the active sheet. Just because you are looping does not automatically assign the sheet to those ranges. You will need to put `Current.` in front of ALL Range Objects.

The outer loop was not necessary.

I redid the logic on the hide to save some typing:

```
Sub HideEmptyRows()

    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim current As Worksheet


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each current In Worksheets
        ' This code hides the adv and group merch rows
        For Each cell In current.Range("EQ29:EQ51")
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = cell.Value = 0
        Next cell

        ' This code hides the consulting rows
        For Each cell In current.Range("EQ61:EQ172")
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = cell.Value = 0
        Next cell
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```